# 'onClick' event affects state of all components, instead of just one

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make an interactive grid that, when you click on a cell, it increments a number on that specific cell only. Instead, when I click on a cell, the entire grid increments, and not the one cell.

I made React print out the ID of the button that was clicked. It only outputs one (correct) ID. I made sure that I passed a function `() => {}` instead of directly calling it. Trying to remove the arrow function results in React complaining that `this is undefined`.

I am aware that this may not be the best way (who am I kidding, this is the most horrible way) of making an interactive grid, but please bear with me:

```
  handleCellClick(id) {
    let cells = this.state.cells.slice()
    cells[id].level = cells[id].level + 1 // Increment ONLY ONE CELL
    console.log(cells[id]) // Logging to console only outputs one id, but it changes all of them?
    this.setState({ cells: cells });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="board">
        {
          Array(resolution).fill(null).map((_, x) => { // Represents the rows
            return (
              <div className='cellRow' key={x}>
                {
                  Array(resolution).fill(null).map((_, y) => { // Represents the columns
                    let id = (x * resolution) + y
                    return (
                      <Cell
                        key={id}
                        onClick={() => { this.handleCellClick(id) }} // This is where it binds the click event
                        data={this.state.cells[id]}
                      />
                    )
                  })
                }
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
        <p> {this.state.debug} </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I expected that upon clicking one cell, by the code above, only that cell should increment, but instead, when actually testing it, it increments all the cells.

[image: The array seems to be built properly.]

Connecting to React DevTools shows that each cell has a different item in the array.

Here is the constructor function.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCellClick = this.handleCellClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cells: Array(resolution * resolution).fill({
        level: 0,
        owner: null,
      }), // 5x5 for 25 in total
      turn: 'red'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like when setting your state, you're setting the entire array variable to a new value, rather than a particular item in the array.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use `this` in an arrow function?

Comment: Using this in arrow function will refer to the proper scope here, because arrows don't create context. Therefore it will refer to the class scope, and reference the methods properly.

Comment: I based this on the Intro to React tutorial on reactjs.org. It uses `this` on arrow functions, so I thought it was fine.

Comment: `cells[id]` should only refer to one specific cell, though... How could it be setting it to all the cells?

Comment: if all cells are incrementing I think your cell ids are the same. Did you log all cell id in render metho?

Comment: No, but doesn't `let id = (x*resolution) + y` mean that all the ids should be different? Looking at the `key` prop, they all have different numbers assigned to them, which should also mean that cell ids are different for each cell.

Comment: I agree with @mstfyldz I think you should triple check the logic in this area and ensure that your array is being built properly to begin with.

Comment: Updated the question regarding your concerns.

Comment: try to do cells[0] === cells[1] . all cells can be the same objects

Comment: @UladzislauUlasenka, `console.log(cells[0] === cells[1] ? "What?" : "Nope :(");` outputs `What?` which means that all the items in the array actually refer to only one object... so that's what's causing it :(

Comment: I posted my constructor, to see if what i'm doing there causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are populating your state.cells with the same object so when you change id of one cell object it triggers others. Can you change your constructor like below and try

```
class Board extends React.Component {
   const cell = {
     level: 0,
     owner: null,
     turn: 'red'
   };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCellClick = this.handleCellClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      cells: Array(resolution * resolution).fill(Object.create(cell))
  }
```